# Webform Master page MVC PartialRender server event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, webforms

OK so I have a webforms project I am wanting to start doing MVC instead. I would like the MVC pages to use the Webforms master page until I can get things transferred over more to MVC. I have this working with a solution I have found you can find listed below (This project works really well except the server event)

https://github.com/MicahArmantrout/BlackMagicMVC

[image]

My problem is that server side events in the master page are not firing. When you load the project up if you click on **"Click Me!"** the button will fire a server event and the Text will change to **"You clicked me".**

[image]

If you goto **"Click For MVC"** (Which is a MVC Partial Render)  and then click the **"Click Me!"** the server event never fires. Any idea why and if this can be fixed ?

**Note:** This is not just a exercise I have a place in a application where this would be extremely useful.If you want to understand this project more please see

http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/ASPNET-MVC-3-Razor-C-and-VBNET-WebForms-A-Tale-of-Black-Magic-Voodoo.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of server side events in MVC. And MVC is not going to wire up the client side events and translate them to server side event handlers the way ASP.Net WebForms does.

You have these options:

- Recreate master page in MVC (`_Layout.cshtml`) and then handle button clicks in your controller. Depending on your design, some refactoring would be needed. You need to decide how or who handles those button clicks.  You can probably get away with handling some of them in a Base Controller, but I would suggest to take a second look at what you're doing in master and how you can translate them on MVC.
- Do the other way round - define you master page in MVC, and render that in your webforms.

Ideally, your master page should not be having any business functions anyway. It should be nothing more than Navigation and style. As long as you adhere to this, migrating to MVC won't be that painful.

Comment: Yes but the masterpage is still in Webforms so shouldn't that portion be wired up ? As far as business logic should not be in the master page ... I agree .... I have inherited this project so its not really a choice I have :)

Comment: Not in the partial view. `runat=server` is the secret sauce here. MVC has no idea what the means, only webForms understands that.

Comment: Cool I guess that's a obvious answer but for a guy coming from the webforms world I really appreciate your help!